# Hipchat 2.2.1080 on ubuntu 64bit 12.04 flashes webcam on startup

Tags: ubuntu, skype, webcam, privacy

I recently updated to hipchat version 2.2.1080 and everytime I start it up it flashes the webcam.  By this, I mean the light on my cam flashes.  It flashes only for a second then turns off.  Does anyone experience this? Does anyone know why this happens?  It is rather unerving because other applications that support video chat, like skype, do no such thing.

I have filed a help ticket directly with hipchat but until they respond I was hoping that someone knew what was going on

Thank you

Comment: Atlassian is early in the development of the screen and camera sharing parts of hipchat, so I'm not too surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlassian is early in the development of the screen and camera sharing parts of hipchat, so I'm not too surprised.

However, it looks like they've just fixed this in the Windows version (May 28, 2014 v2.2.1131) -

https://www.hipchat.com/release_notes/qtwindows

```
Delay video initialization until it is used the first time - no blinking web cam lights -
```

Answer (score 0):

The response I receieved from Hipchat Help was:

> Thanks for the heads up on this issue. Our Linux dev is aware of it
>   and we have a bug open to fix it. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Looks like they've just fixed this in the Windows version (May 28, 2014 v2.2.1131) - Delay video initialization until it is used the first time - no blinking web cam lights - https://www.hipchat.com/release_notes/qtwindows